# How to ramp up users every second with different URLs and stack the URL requests with the next user?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

My requirement is as below:

I have 5 different URLs and I have to ramp up 5 users, with each new user added every second. However, when every new virtual user gets added, the previous user should also hit their URL again. Something like below:

Ramp-up 5s:

**Loop 1: sec1**.

VU1 URL1

**Loop 2: sec2.**

VU1 URL1
VU2 URL2.

**Loop 3: sec3.**

VU1 URL1.

VU2 URL2.

VU3 URL3 and so on.

How to achieve it in JMeter? Is there some other tool where we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put the URLs into a text file, each on a new line and use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to read the line from file equal to the number of the current thread (virtual user), something like:

```
${__groovy(new File('urls.txt').readLines().get(ctx.getThreadNum()),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. But, looks like in the above solution, in each loop, all the users are hitting their respective URLs. That's not the challenge I am trying to solve. I want when one user is added every second, they hit their URL and plus the previous user(s) too hit their URLs. So, in Loop 1, VU1, Second 1, only URL1 should be hit by VU1.
In the next second, VU2 should hit URL2 and VUI1 should hit their URL1 too.
The idea is to gradually ramp up as it would happen in a real scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There are SaaS platforms online that do just that, eg https://rungutan.com